# Problem to upload file on server php bitnami

Tags: php, bitnami

I'm deploying a web server, and the server is running bitnami. When I try to upload a file to the server, it returns 400 errors, bad request. I read the error log of bitnami (because the code works on another server) and It has the following message:

> [Wed Feb 10 15:11:33.103754 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10113:tid 140226278139648] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: [client xxxxxxxx:64905] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: http://xxxxxxx/test.php

I have verified the limit to upload, timely execution, php.ini, etc. And I search for information about the error but I can't find information about it. What do the reasons maybe? Thank you for your comments

Comment: It could be related to `mod_reqtimeout` of Apache not using correct values. You could try adding adding these lines to your `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`:


```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```


Please remember to restart the Apache service so the changes are effective.
I hope it helps